# Multiple File uploader, change span contents and rename to file selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm trying to update the span text for my each relative file uploader I have on a page so that when a file is selected, the words "Choose a file..." are replaced with the filename.

How do I do this Working [Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nh71xLhk/1/)

**My HTML markup**

```
<p class="hide_this last" style="display: none;">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-05">
     <input type="file" name="file-05" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file-05" aria-invalid="false">
  </span>
  <label for="file-05"><span>Choose a file...</span></label><br>
  <a class="del_file" href="#">Remove</a>
</p>
```

**My JS**

```
//hide all inputs except the first one
$('p.hide_this').not(':eq(0)').hide();

//functionality for add-file link
$('a.add_file').on('click', function(e){
  //show by click the first one from hidden inputs
  $('p.hide_this:not(:visible):first').show('slow');
  e.preventDefault();
});

//functionality for del-file link
$('a.del_file').on('click', function(e){

//var init
var input_parent = $(this).parent();
var input_wrap = input_parent.find('span');

//reset field value
input_wrap.html(input_wrap.html());

//hide by click
input_parent.hide('slow');
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [Check the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nh71xLhk/6/)

1. By using the change function we can trigger the event and also we can get the file name
2. `$(this).attr('id');` this will help to get the selector id

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
          var filename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
            var idname = $(this).attr('id');
          $('.'+idname).next().find('span').html(filename);  
          });
      });
```

Check the updated fiddle you can use the below function to trim the chracters

```
var str = "Hello Worsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfld!";
var length = str.length -20 ;
var n = str.substring(0, str.length- length );    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

**Edit 2**

[Fiddle update 2](https://jsfiddle.net/nh71xLhk/7/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
                 var str= $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
                 var length = str.length -20 ;
                 var filename = str.substring(0, str.length- length );  
                var idname = $(this).attr('id');
              $('.'+idname).next().find('span').html(filename);  
              });
          });
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. I know this could be another question but how easy is it to concatenate the file name. So add an ellipses after say the first 20 characters of each filename?

Comment: Im sorry i didnt understand @egr103

Comment: When you upload a file that has a really long filename, is there a way to cut the title off after 20 characters or something? This will trim the what would be a very long title so it looks OK on the page